# CAlayer in AVmutablevideo composition

Tags: ios, xcode, avfoundation, calayer

I am trying to initialize the video in `videoasset CGSize` for the `CAlayer`.

```
CGSize videoSize = [videoasset naturalSize];
```

Unfortunately, `naturalSize` is deprecated. What can I use instead of naturalSize?

Answer (score 1):

Create an [AVPlayerItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/AVPlayerItem) from the asset, and read its `CGSize presentationSize` property.

You can then use the `videoGravity` property of the `AVPlayerLayer` object to scale the video to your liking.